# Activity with SearchView close with left arrow

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I have a HomeActivity and I start a SearchActivity that contains a SearchView in the toolbar.

I set the SearchView to be initially expanded using this: *search.ExpandActionView();*.
This is the SearchActivity code in C# but no problem if you can help in java/kotlin...

```
 public class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity
 {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_search);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        this.SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_search_places, menu);
        IMenuItem search = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search_places);
        search.ExpandActionView();
       // var searchView = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView)search.ActionView;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is menu_search_places.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <item
     android:id="@+id/action_search_places"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
     app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
     android:title="Search for a place"/>
</menu>
```

The top left arrow seems to be linked with the SearchView - it collapses the SearchView.

Also *onOptionsItemSelected* is not triggered

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
    //
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Can we modify this so **when I click the arrow to close the SearchActivity instead of collapsing the Searchview** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `setOnActionExpandListener` on search menu item inside `OnCreateOptionsMenu`. This way you can listen to change when the search view is collapsing or expanding.

```
searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
        override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // do something
            return true
        }

        override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // do something
            return true
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I added finish() inside onMenuItemActionCollapse() there is some delay: the SearchView collapses then the activity closes.  If there was some way to close the activity immediately before collapsing the SearchView